# How to disable ALT and APPs Key shortcuts in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, conemu

I am using Palemoon (Firefox 64bit fork) version 25.3.1 opening inside a split window inside Conemu.

Conemu uses APPs key for split resizing, when i am inside a placemoon browser split window, and I press APP + Enter to enlarge it, it open the mouse right click menu. If i try and use APP + Left to resize, it highlights a text field.

How can I disable ALT and APP keyboard shortcuts in Firefox.

Comment: Don't know if it ever possible in PaleMoon, may be it will be better to contact its maintainer? The workaround is here: http://conemu.github.io/en/ChildGui.html

Comment: I think if someone shows how to do it in Firefox, i can try it in Palemoon as its a fork of firefox